# login to http server from J2ME app

Tags: java, multithreading, java-me

I have a login Midlet contains text field and password fields. then i have two action commands to login or cancel.
When user press login, the app ask to activate the internet connection and make the HTTP request in another `thread`.

**Here is my question:**
I need the app to wait for the response from the server which in another `thread` and do the rest of code.

This is login Midlet

```
public class MyloginMedlet extends MIDlet implements CommandListiner {
private TextField username;
private TextField password;
public MyloginMedlet() {
// steps required to create the login ui here
}
public void startApp() {
// app starts here and disply the ui elements
}
public void pauseApp() {
}
public void destroyApp(boolean unconditional) {
    notifyDestroyed();
}
/*
* Here things gets intersting
*/
public void commandAction(Command c, Displayable d) {
    String label = c.getLabel();
    if (label.equals("Cancel") || label.equals("Exit")) {
        destroyApp(true);
    } else if (label.equals("Login")) {
        Thread t = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
             serverResponse = connect(userName.getString(), password.getString());
            }
          };
          t.start();
          if (serverResponse == "isValidUser") {
                // Go to app dashboard
         } else {
                // Alert User with failed login
          }
    }
//
// Conect through HTTP
private String connect(String name, String password2) {
    String url = "http://192.168.1.90/checkUser.php";
    // String url = getAppProperty("NetworkThreading.URL");

    try {
        // Query the server and retrieve the response.
        HttpConnection hc = (HttpConnection) Connector.open(url);
        InputStream in = hc.openInputStream();

        // Pull back the server's response. If a content length is not
        // specified, we'll just read 255 bytes.
        int contentLength = (int) hc.getLength();
        if (contentLength == -1)
            contentLength = 255;
        byte[] raw = new byte[contentLength];
        int length = in.read(raw);

        // Clean up.
        in.close();
        hc.close();

        // Show the response to the user.
        String s = new String(raw, 0, length);
        System.out.println(s);
        return s;
//          Alert a = new Alert("Response", s, null, null);
//          a.setTimeout(Alert.FOREVER);
//          mainScreen.setCurrent(a);
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            Alert a = new Alert("Exception", ioe.toString(), null, null);
            a.setTimeout(Alert.FOREVER);
            // mDisplay.setCurrent(a, mMainForm);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

The `Thread` isn't wait for HTTP request to finish. it always go to alert area (commented area). also i tried to put the check code in the thread but no succeed.

Any one help me to make the execution wait for thread until it finish. i tried `join()` but code end with hang up.

Answer (score 0):

finally i find a solution on how to solve this:

- When you call `run()` method, you should create a form (Screen) to inform user to wait until thread finish it's work.

`Form f = new Form("Please Waite...");
f.append("Please Waite...");
Display.getDisplay(this).setCurrent(f);`

- Put this code in commandAction method before you call `run()` method.